# Adding a loading text while an AJAX function is executing

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I've been trying to add a loading text that would display while an AJAX function is being executed for a long while now, and all of my attempts (which includes using the ajaxStart and ajaxStop, among other things) haven't been working at all. Any help is appreciated!

[Here](http://rtruong.x10host.com/home/rtruongx/public_html/Hour17.html) is the webpage that the script in question is located on, if you want to see it in action. The way it works is that you enter in a url and the function will grab the meta tags of that URL.

Meanwhile, here is the relevant HTML, Javascript, and PHP:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Keywords Grabber</title>

            <script src="ajax.js"></script>
            <script>
                function display(content) {
                    document.getElementById("displaydiv").innerHTML = content;
                }
                window.onload = function () {
                    document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function () {
                        var url = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
                        doAjax("metatags.php", "url=" + url, "display", "post", 0);
                    }
                }
            </script>


        </head>
        <body>
            http://<input type="text" id="txt1" value="" />
            <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Get Keywords" />
            <h3>Keywords Received:</h3>
            <div id="displaydiv"></div>



        </body>
    </html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 function getXMLHttpRequest() {
    try {
        try {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e) {
            return new ActiveXObject("Msml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    catch(e) {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
}
function doAjax(url, query, callback, reqtype, getxml) {
    var myreq = getXMLHttpRequest();
    myreq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (myreq.readyState == 4) {
            if (myreq.status == 200) {
                var item = myreq.responseText;
                if (getxml == 1) item = myreq.responseXML;
                eval(callback + '(item)'); 
        }
    }
}
if (reqtype.toUpperCase() == "POST") {
    requestPOST(url, query, myreq);
    } else {
        requestGET(url, query, myreq);
    }
    }

function requestGET(url, query, req) {
    var myRandom = parseInt(Math.random()*99999999);
    if (query == '') {
        var callUrl = url + '?rand=' + myRandom;
    } else {
        var callUrl = url + '?' + query + '&rand=' + myRandom;
    }
    req.open("GET", callUrl, true);
    req.send(null);
}
function requestPOST(url, query, req) {
    req.open("POST", url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.send(query);
}
```

**PHP**

```
    <?php
$tags = @get_meta_tags('http://'.$_REQUEST['url']);
$result = $tags['keywords'];
if(strlen($result) > 0) {
    echo $result;
} else {
    echo "No keywords metatag is available.";
}
?>
```

Comment: lol, too late to read all of that.  Anyway all you do is have a loading message hidden, then show it just before the ajax call then for the callback of the ajax function hide the loader. it;s not really that hard.  I would look into using jQuery  $.post( url, {data}, function(){ });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
 <div id="loading" style="display:none;">loading</div>
```

Javascript

```
 $('#loading').css('display', 'block');
 $.post(url, {}, function(data){
      $('#loading').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: Hey there! I feel like an absolute idiot for saying this, but how do I implement the JavaScript portion of what you've posted into my script? I feel like this is such a basic question to ask, but I'm just really confused right now. Thank you, though!

Comment: http://jquery.com/ - it's a javascript framework, and makes life a whole lot simpler